# Find a value in an array from row and column index

Tags: c#, arrays

So I have a 5 by 6 two dimensional array(A). From this array(A) i would like to return a value based on the input of row and column by the user. What I have so far...

```
private int FindValue(int[,] A, int row, int col)
{
    richTextBox1.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (A[i, j] == A)
            {
                return A[i, j];
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int row = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    int col = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want to search for an item in the array and return its row/col values? Or do you just want to see if the array contains an item? Or do you just want to return the item at [row, col]?

Comment: It seems OP just wants the value at the position(row,column) :)

Comment: What's wrong with plain old `return A[row, col]`?

Comment: @Vinay I was assuming the OP would know he could just do `A[row,col]`, and wouldn't ask this question if that's all he wanted... Perhaps it's just validation of row/col he needs, in which case dasblinkenlight has the answer.

Comment: I do agree with you @MatthewWatson

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes Vinay, I'm looking for the value at the position the user enters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure why are checking

```
 if (A[i, j] == A)
```

instead you can simply return:

```
private int FindValue(int[,] A, int row, int col)
{
    if (row >= 0 &&  row < A.GetLength(0) && col >= 0 && col < A.GetLength(1))
        return A[row, col];
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: That if statement was where I was trying to return the value and I wasn't sure how to go about it. Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 2):

If the user inputs both `row` and `col`, you do not need to search; no loops are necessary. All you need is checking the entered array coordinates against the limits for your array, and returning `A[row,col]` when they are correct, or `-1` when they are wrong:

```
private int FindValue(int[,] A, int row, int col) {
    if (row < 0 || row >= 5 || col < 0 || col >= 6) return -1;
    return A[row, col];
}
```

If you were searching for a *value* in an array (i.e. users enter `X`, and you tell them the `row` and `col`) then you would need two loops, comparing `A[row,col]` to `X`, and returning `row` and `col` back to the user if you find a match.

Comment: This is what I was trying to achieve. Though I did not know that if i returned a[row, col] it would return the value and not the coordinates. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: If you want to get the value from A[,] you don't need to loop through. `A[i,j]` would be good enough. Also do not forget that array index starts with 0.